# Is there a better way to use C++ concurrency than below?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to learn the basics of threading, mutex, etc. Following the documentation and examples from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/). In the below code I am getting the output as expected. Questions:

1. Want to confirm if there is any pitfall that I am missing? How can we improve the code below?
2. On which line did my thread tried to take the mutex or is waiting for mutex? (Is it after line 11 or on line 11?)
3. Is it ok to include `cv.notify_all();` in the thread code?

```
#include<mutex>
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<condition_variable>

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
int currentlyRequired = 1;

void work(int id){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx); // Line 11
    while(currentlyRequired != id){
        cv.wait(lock);
    }
    std::cout<<"Thread # "<<id<<"\n";
    currentlyRequired++;
    cv.notify_all();
}

int main(){
    std::thread threads[10];
    
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        threads[i] = std::thread(work, i+1);
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        threads[i].join();
    }
    return 0;
}

/* Current Output:
Thread # 1
Thread # 2
Thread # 3
Thread # 4
Thread # 5
Thread # 6
Thread # 7
Thread # 8
Thread # 9
Thread # 10
Program ended with exit code: 0
*/
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Your code doesn't really make any sense (as opposed to the example you linked to, which tries to ensure that all threads and up and spinning before "letting them loose").

Comment: IMHO, you code is correct. However, it effectively serializes the work of the threads. Such an effect can be achieved much easier without threads. I use condition variables when organizing something like pipes: Thread 1 does something in a loop and produces some data which is passed to thread 2 at end of iteration step. Thread 2 is waiting on results from thread 1 and starts to process them as soon as the first results are handed over from thread 1 while thread 1 continues with next iteration (to produce new results).

Comment: Condition variables and unlocking... I needed a while until I understood it. ;-) Line 11 locks the mutex. (That's a necessary pre-condition for `wait()`.) The `wait()` unlocks the mutex again and suspends the thread until a notification wakes up the thread. Before returning from `wait()` the mutex is locked again.

Comment: Google `spurious wakeup`. You should know about it too when using condition variables

Comment: FYI: [std::condition_variable::wait()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) (Roughly the same as described above but a bit more seriously.) ;-)

Comment: @odyss-jii I am actually trying to create dependency between the threads. It is exactly like what Scheff said.

Comment: @Asesh It _does_ look like OP knows about that: `while(currentlyRequired != id) { cv.wait(lock); }`

Comment: @rahuljain1311 You _could_ `cv.notify_all();` _after_ the lock has been released though.

Comment: @rahuljain1311 You are creating a dependency. But it's literally the opposite of what we're looking for in multi-threading. You've created 10 wonderful threads that hardware permitting can all run in parallel then very carefully made sure that only 1 is (usefully) running at any one time. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost I recommend you read the documentation here: [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

It's a little more discursive about the key points you need to conform to to use a condition variable for inter-thread waiting and notification.

I think your code measures up.
Your code obtains the lock in line 11 as you think. Other constructors of `unique_lock` will adopt a mutex previously locked (by the current thread) or not locked (by current thread) and lock it when requested (that would be `lock.lock();` here).

What you have is right. You check the relevant data holding the lock.
Wait then unlocks it (through the `unique_lock`) and awaits notification.
When notified it stops waiting, locks it again and loops to check the condition.
Eventually the condition is true and (still holding the lock) each thread continues on to do its 'work'.
The 'waiting' side looks correct. The 'notifying' side also looks correct.
The data for the condition *must* be modified holding the mutex to ensure the correct synchronisation of checking the data and going into the waiting state that the condition-variable manages.

You correctly `notify_all()`. Even though logically (in this example) only one thread needs to wake up there's no way of picking it out to be the target of `notify_one()`.

So all the threads wake up (if suspended), check their condition and exactly one of them identifies its turn and runs.

Common wisdom (and my experience) is that it's better (and valid) to `notify_all()` not holding the lock because the waiting threads wake up to block (on the lock). But I'm told some platforms run better notifying under the lock. Welcome to the world of platform dependence...

So in terms of implementing a condition-variable I think that's valid and pretty much textbook.

It's good to see the `join()` as well. I have a bugbear about coders not joining to threads.
It's one of those that at small scale and load you get away with but when the application scales and experiences high-load can start to cause problems and confusion.

The problem I have with what you've done has no parallelism.

What you've achieved is a daisy-chain. The very intention is to ensure only one thread is 'doing work' at once and they do so in strict order.

To take advantage of concurrency we want to maximise parallelism - the number of parallel running threads doing 'the work' (i.e. not the housekeeping of inter-thread communication) and your code is literally (because you did it right!) guaranteed to ensure there is never more than one thread running and the code is due to housekeeping guaranteed to be slightly slower than a single-threaded application (which would be a for loop!).

So it gets top-marks for program correctness but no marks for being useful!

Both the examples on cplusplus.con and cppreference.com are little better in my view.

The best introductory example is some kind of producer consumer model.
That's closer to an *actually* useful pattern.

Try something as simple as one producer thread is counting up through the integers and multiple consumer threads square them and output them.
A key point will be that if you're doing it right the squares *won't* in general come out in sequential order.

These examples are like teaching recursion with factorial. Sure it's recursive but recursion is a terrible way to calculate factorial!
Sure your multi-threading (the other examples) are valid but they're outright contrived to do nothing useful in parallel!

Please don't take that as a criticism. As a 'tooth cutting' exercise what you've got is top-class. The next task is to do something that uses concurrency *usefully!*.

The problem is we don't want condition-variables! By definition they make threads wait for each other and that reduces parallelism. We need them and they do their job. But a design that reduces the amount of mutual waiting (either on locks or conditions) is usually better because the enemy here is waiting, blocking or (worst) spinning instead of suspended waiting/blocking.

Here's a better design for your task. Better *because* it entirely avoids the condition-variable!!

```
#include<mutex>
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>

std::mutex mtx;
int currentlyRequired = 1;

void work(int id){
    std::lock_guard<decltype(mtx)> guard(mtx);
    const auto old{currentlyRequired++};
    std::cout<<"Thread # "<<id<<" "<< old << "-> " <<currentlyRequired<< "\n";
}

int main(){
    std::thread threads[10];
    
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        threads[i] = std::thread(work, i+1);
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        threads[i].join();
    }
    std::cout << "Final result: " << currentlyRequired << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Specimen output:

```
Thread # 7 1-> 2
Thread # 8 2-> 3
Thread # 9 3-> 4
Thread # 10 4-> 5
Thread # 6 5-> 6
Thread # 5 6-> 7
Thread # 4 7-> 8
Thread # 3 8-> 9
Thread # 2 9-> 10
Thread # 1 10-> 11
Final result: 11
```

Which thread does which increment will vary. But final result is always 11.
It's still no good because there's still no parallelism because the work is all done under a single lock. That's why we need a more interesting task.

Have fun.

Comment: This is a lot of text and I admit not having read it all. But you seem to be saying that OP’s code is OK, when it is definitely not — its handling of the condition variable is incorrect, for one. At a cursory glance your own code probably works but it doesn’t really need to use a lock, using atomic update would be sufficient.

Comment: @KonradRudolph How so?

Comment: https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-be-aware-of-the-traps-of-condition-variables

Comment: @KonradRudolph He definitely waits on a predicate.
Barring the use of the lambda version of wait (which is equivalent) his code is almost a copy of `waitingForWork()` in the first example presented as 'do it right'. 
I still don't see a problem.

Comment: Ah, right, I hadn’t taken into account that the loop is guarded by the lock.

Comment: @KonradRudolph No worries. I did think about using an atomic in my example. But I didn't want to go too far from what he'd got as an example. If we go too far we replace the whole shootin' match with `currentlyRequired=11`! That's part of why I think it a poor example. I think he's using it correctly but not achieving anything useful by it! Like teaching people recursion on factorial and then people leave the lesson thinking recursion is a good way to implement factorial.